# SVG Mask video and position absolute

Tags: svg, video, css-position, mask, masking

I am trying to mask a video with an SVG. When I add the position absolute to the CSS my mask works but knocks out other elements on my page, eg. some lottie files and chages the dimensions of my slider further down the page.

When I remove the position absolute, the mask obviously doesn't work but the other elements are now fine.

The is the code :

```
<video id="vidmask" autoplay playsinline muted loop preload poster="http://i.imgur.com/xHO6DbC.png">
    <source src="https://808images.local/wp-content/uploads/2023/04/WEBSITE_COMING_SOON_loop_final_V3_fb_1080p_2.mp4" />
    </video>
  <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 500 400" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid slice">
    <defs>
      <mask id="svgmask2" x="0" y="0" width="100%" height="100%" >
         <rect fill="#ffffff" x="0" y="0" width="100%" height="100%" />
        <rect class="rect-vid-left" fill="#000000" width="33%" height="64%"/>
      <rect class="rect-vid-cent" fill="#000000" x="34%" width="33%" height="100%"/>
      <rect class="rect-vid-right" fill="#000000" x="68%" width="33%" height="70%"/>
</mask>
    </defs>
    <rect fill="#fffff" x="0" y="0" width="100%" height="100%" />
  </svg>
```

And the CSS:

```
video{
  max-width: 100%;
}
svg{    
  position:absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  fill: white;
}
svg rect{
    mask: url(#svgmask2);
}
```

I have created 3 separate rectangles classes so that I can animate them afterwards

Is there any way to use this SVG mask without the position absolute? I have seen other methods but with them I can't animate the elements of the SVG.

Thanks for your help

https://codepen.io/Griff-808-web/pen/abQXMpb